# Removing the border around dash

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I'd like to remove the huge dotted border around the dash in ubuntu 16.04.
Google isn't my friend lately and I just can't find any result...
Compizconfig doesn't contain any option for this.
Can someone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to describe what you mean by "huge dotted border around the dash"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting to not display the border around the dash, when the dash is not full screen. The only way to make the border not be visible, is to maximize the dash by clicking the maximize button in the top panel, while the dash is open.

Comment: oh... what a shame... it looks really horrible in my opinion... are you sure there isn't any workaround for this?

Comment: The "workaround" is to maximize the dash. If you don't like that, feel free to file a bug about the border, using `ubuntu-bug unity` or grab the source for unity and make a patch to submit for adding a setting.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll try what I can! Have a nice day!